# How to generate a sublist topTen Map using Stream function?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a very common task that I really want to solve using the stream function of Java 8. I am still trying to get to grips with most parts involving this so I hope I didn't understand anything wrong.

I have a database from which I take the data to generate a LinkedHashMap and pass it on to my function to extract the top n values from it and return the map with only these n values in it in a orderd way. I really want to solve this using the stream function for educational purposes (more personal, dont have a teacher asking this of me).

I build this function expecting that the stream function does the algorithm in the background but once I display the chart with this data it is obvious that it isnt correct. I tried to find my answer in the documentation/web but I couldn't find anything that helped suficiantly.

What I came up with so far isn't working right and I kind of have the feeling that I might have understood something wrong here:

```
private Map<String, Number> getTopValuesDataMap(Map<String, Number> chartDataMap) {
    return chartDataMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(Number::intValue).reversed())).limit(12)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Edit:

It seems the error lies somewhere else. As has been noticed that this function does work correctly after all. Need to do more testing.

thanks anyway

Comment: Define "isnt working right". Post a complete example, with hard-coded inputs, the actual output you get, and the expected output. The only potential problem I see is that you're comparing the numbers using intValue, so 1.2 and 1.9 are considered equal by your comparator.

Comment: Your code does work for integer values, but not for numbers with floating point. See: http://ideone.com/uAq6Z3

Comment: @JBNizet I know the output is wrong because I get following results: {KR=100, EG=54, AR=52, ES=28, GT=28, ZA=22, LT=22, MA=22, XX=18, LI=18, ML=17, HU=16} but I should get something more like : {AT 4086,CH 2562,CO 1932, DE 47285, ES 5323,GB 4029,IT 5091,NL 2693, ZA 1423}

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, @MarkusMildner, it’s useful. When giving such, it’s better to edit the question and include it there.